# Confirm JMS message into subprocess

Tags: tibco, tibco-designer

Is there any way to confirm a JMS message in a subprocess?

I have process A that starts with a JMS Queue Receiver (or JMS Topic Subscriber). It calls process B which has to confirm the message received - I'm using Tibco EMS Explicit acknowledge mode.

This will allow me to reuse some parts. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. The confirm always has to be in the same process as the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

In a well-designed architecture you do not want to split the messaging (and confirm) layer but rather push all functional processing into a sub-process having a result parameter indicating if the initial message shall be kept (defer processing to a later time by not confirming) or mark it as "processed" (and confirm it).

By default, all (JMS) messages are auto-confirmed so an explicit confirm is a design choice made by you (based on a particular consumption model) in the config tab of the process starter/step. You should only use this if you know what happens with that message and if a processing deferral is possible. Most loosely coupled messaging is not "transactional" (except you decide to take the extra mile) in a DB sense - so rather stick to the auto-confirm if you have no special handling demand! BW/EMS are quite good in handling (reasonably small) messages so NOT auto-confirming can create re-deliveries within milliseconds and flood your whole system (heap space) if not handled properly.